# Association bonus is not awarded

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation

Whenever a user reaches 200 reputations in Stack Overflow, they will got 100 reputation as bonus. That means there should be no user with reputation of range 201-299.

But I found multiple users on this range. How is it possible?

Comment: I face same problem When I reach 200 they give me 100 reputation point and my reputation reach 360 but next day it's 209 again.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you got any links?

There are two cases where this could happen:

1. The user doesn't have accounts on other sites.
2. Stack Overflow isn't the site where they have the most reputation. If they hit 200 on Super User (say) their account on there will jump from 200 to 300, but their account on Stack Overflow will jump from 123 to 223 (for example).

Answer (score 7):

First you can lose reputation by downvotes and bounties.

Second, if one associated site has more than 200 rep, you get 100 bonus on all other sites and the current site. But this happens only once.

Third, if you have no associated accounts, you get no bonus.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, the association bonus is applied **when you join a new Stack Exchange network site**.  It is applied to the site that you join - you start there with 101 reputation rather than 1.

As you can earn the 200 rep to get the global association bonus on *any* network site, you can get the following situation:

1. User has 150 reputation on Stack Overflow.
2. User gets 200 reputation on another Stack Exchange site so gets the association bonus *everywhere*.
3. User now has 250 reputation on Stack Overflow (in the middle of the range you stated above).

Comment: That's incorrect, the association bonus is awarded once on all sites, including the first site you reach 200 rep on.

Comment: The bonus is applied to  on every site you are having account after single site you got 200 rep.

Answer (score 1):

Another Situation

When user has 350 reputation score and it offer a bounty of 100 reputation then 350-100 = 250.